# make .d.ts for external library file available for project

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, vite, .d.ts

I have a closed-source plain JS library that will be included via a `<script>` tag pointing to a CDN. I would like to author my own type definition file for this library so I can reference a global object that the library provides once loaded into the HTML page.

So far I am having trouble getting my IDE to show me that it recognizes the .d.ts file.

I have the following project structure:

```
project-folder/
 - tsconfig.json
 - src/
definitions/
- mylibrary.d.ts
```

In tsconfig I have the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "typeRoots": ["../definitions/"]
  },
  "include": ["./src"]
}
```

In mylibrary.d.ts I have the following:

```
interface example {
  hello: boolean;
}

declare namespace MyLibraryObject {
    const testing: string; 
    function foo(bar: string): void;
}
```

Then in main.ts I attempt to use any of the types defined in the d.ts file such as:

```
const test: example = { hello: true };

console.log(MyLibraryObject.testing);
MyLibaryObject.foo();
```

But TS cannot find the definitions for these, as seen here:

[image: screenshot of TS errors in vscode]

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, the solution was to expand the set of "included" paths in the tsconfig file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["../definitions/"]
  },
  "include": ["./src", "../definitions/"]
}
```